# What's the best way to make an Assembly compiler in Python available online?

Tags: python, django, assembly, web, web-applications

The compiler works by receiving a file that contains the macro assembler source code then, it generates two files, one is the list and the other one is the hex file.

Everything works alright while offline but I want to make it online.

In this case, the user will provide an MC68HC11 assembly source code file to my server (I already have the server up and running) and after this, my server will compile it using the Python script I wrote and then it will give the user an option to download the list and the hex file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put the two output files into a single zip file, send a doctype header indicating it's in zip format and send the output as raw data.
The alternative is to use httprequest for the client to request each file in turn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the httprequest solution works just fine :)